# Convert string to respective data type ie. int or long (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, int, long-integer, type-conversion, factors

```
temp=input()
l=list(map(int,temp.split()))
count=0
for i in range (1,min(l[0],l[1])+1):
    if l[0]%i==0 and l[1]%i==0:
        count+=1
print (count)
```

Above code takes 2 or more numbers and finds count of common factors. the range for these numbers is 1 to 10**12.

How to handle both int and long data types in this code? Kindly help.

Comment: there is no distinction between long and int in python3. (long does not exist...)

Comment: not sure but are you planning to iterate from 1 to 10**12? because that's a bad idea ...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I will find a better way once I resolve this issue. The code is not giving output for huge values.

Answer (score 6):

As opposed to Python 2, Python 3 doesn't distinguish between `int` and `long` (`long` is gone from Python 3). It's just an integer which can be even longer than 64-bit.

From Python 3 documentation

> [Integers have unlimited precision.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex)

Comment: python 2 does the difference. there's no need to copy hiro's comment into a less detailed answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I haven't noticed that comment. Either way I've marked it as community so the question has some answer.

Comment: surprisingly I wasn't able to find an exact duplicate, so upvoting your answer.

Comment: @Qeek the code isn't running for numbers like these two,10000000000 15000000000 but is running for these, 10000000000 1500000.

Comment: @PrashantSingh You should add more information in to the question like what does "isn't running for numbers like these..." means? Does it print nothing, raise some exception or what? Maybe event better would be create question focusing on your problem instead of  focusing on `int` vs `long` problem.